# promise.all dont working as expected in typescript/javascript with firebase?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, promise

```
getTreeData(): Promise<Node[]>{
    let customerUID;
    const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
    const tree: Node[] = [];
    promises.push(this.firestore.collection('activities').doc(this.codeValue).get().toPromise().then(doc => {
      customerUID = doc.data().customerUID;
      promises.push(this.firestore.collection('customers').doc(customerUID).collection('order').get().toPromise().then(task => {
        task.forEach( doc1 => {
          const node = {name: doc1.id, children: [], parent: null};
          promises.push(this.getChildren(doc1, node).then( children => {
            node.children = children;
            console.log("hi");
            tree.push(node);
          }));
        });
      }));
    }));
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      return tree;
    });
  }

  getChildren(doc: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<firebase.firestore.DocumentData>, parentNode: Node): Promise<Node[]>{
    const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
    const tree: Node[] = [];
    promises.push(doc.ref.collection('children').get().then(task => {
      task.forEach(doc1 => {
        const node = {name: doc1.id, children: [], parent: parentNode};
        promises.push(this.getChildren(doc1, node).then( children => {
          node.children = children;
          console.log("hi");
          tree.push(node);
        }));
      });
    }));
    console.log(promises);
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      return tree;
    });
  }
```

the getTreeData() should return Node[](node in custom interface)that goes to material tree
the main function returns an empty array (promise.all() don't work properly).

Maybe I missed some to the promises.all?.

Maybe I can't return promise.all().then(.....)?

Comment: You seem to be adding more promises to the promise array inside the promises you initially add to the array. That seems like a bad move.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what exactly you expect this code to do.  What does it mean for this code to "work properly"?  You have database queries here, but we can't see the data you're working with.

Comment: I edited my wishes from this function

Comment: You just have a simple race condition.  Basically the only promises that get pushed into your promise array is the outer loop.  Because by the time the inner loop pushes have been done promise.all had already been called.

Comment: That one makes sense @Keith
Can you write a solution, please?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your outer loop you are pushing into your promises array.

But it's only these that get sent to `Promise.all`, this is because the inner loop only starts to get filled when the inner Promises start to complete, and that is in the future.

So if we say flattened that execution order you would get something like.

`outer` `outer` `outer` `outer` `Promise.all` `inner` `inner` etc.

One solution to this is to use `Promise.all` again inside you inner loops.

eg.

```
getTreeData(): Promise<Node[]>{
  let customerUID;
  const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
  const tree: Node[] = [];
  promises.push(this.firestore.collection('activities').
    doc(this.codeValue).get().toPromise().then(doc => {
      const promises: Promise<any>[] = []; //add this
      customerUID = doc.data().customerUID;
      promises.push(this.firestore.collection('customers').
      doc(customerUID).collection('order').get().toPromise().then(task => {
        task.forEach( doc1 => {
          const node = {name: doc1.id, children: [], parent: null};
          promises.push(this.getChildren(doc1, node).then( children => {
            node.children = children;
            console.log("hi");
            tree.push(node);
          }));
        });
      }));
      return Promise.all(promises); //and this
    }));
  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    return tree;
  });
}
```